# Adding text over an image in Bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a carousel with an image that i would like to put text over, but it is not working. The text appears under the image instead of overlayed on top of it

```
<!-- WRAPPER FOR SLIDES -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="active item">
                            <div class="carousel-content">
                                <img src="img/Slide 1.jpg" alt="..." position="relative">
                                <p>TEST</p>
                            </div>

                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>What we do</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>What we Do</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>Who we Are</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle? Usually, the way to get around these things is through relative/absolute positioning.

Answer (score 18):

You could simply `position` the element `absolute`ly just like built-in captions and set the `top`/`bottom`, `left`/`right` offsets.

Note that the carousel captions have `z-index: 10` by default, so you may want to give the positioned element a higher `z-index`:

For instance:

```css
.carousel-content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 5%;
  z-index: 20;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/315" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-content">
        <p>TEST</p>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>What we do</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>What we Do</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h3>Who we Are</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a possible solution:

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/38v09vha/

```
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
                    <div class="absolute-div">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>What we Do</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
                    <div class="absolute-div">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>What we Do</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x315" alt="...">
                    <div class="absolute-div">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h3>What we Do</h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
```

and css:

```
.carousel-caption {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.absolute-div {
    position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
}

.carousel-caption h3 {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
}

.item {
    position:relative;
}
```

Assuming that you want them vertically aligned in the middle of the image—Basically, you'll want to relatively position the slide-items parent div, which will inherit it's height from the combined height of the image and the text. Then, you'll want to create a div that houses the text which has the css attribute `position: absolute`. This element will be a direct child of the relatively positioned parent. This will allow you to absolutely position your text within the nearest relatively positioned element. [See this CSS Tricks tutorial to understand how this works](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/).

This will allow you to position the text over the image, I then went ahead and used table positioning to allow you to vertically center them, although you could go ahead and place them over the image wherever you like.

Answer (score 4):

Hope it help someone, in my case i did it with the following code :

```
<style>
.carousel-caption {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.carousel-caption div {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
}

.trickcenter {
    position: fixed;
    top: 84%; // 50% for perfect centering
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
</style>

<div class="item">
    <img src="images/slider_T02.jpg" alt="Moto de collection">
    <div class="carousel-caption trickcenter">
        <div>HERE THE TEXT YOU WANT</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
    <img src="images/slider_T03.jpg" alt="Véhicule Haut de Gamme">
    <div class="carousel-caption trickcenter">
        <div>HERE THE SECOND TEXT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `card` class on `carousel-item`, and put all of the content inside a `div.card-img-overlay`.

```html
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel carousel-dark slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">

   <div class="carousel-indicators">
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"
         aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1"
         aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
      <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2"
         aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
   </div>

   <div class="carousel-inner">
      
      <div class="carousel-item active card"> <!-- add .card here -->

         <div class="card-img-overlay">
            <!-- h2, p and button is defined here -->
         </div>

         <img src="./path/to/1.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item card"> <!-- add .card here -->

         <div class="card-img-overlay">
            Some text here...
         </div>

         <img src="./path/to/2.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item card"> <!-- add .card here -->

         <div class="card-img-overlay">
            Some text here as well...
         </div>

         <img src="./path/to/3.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Result**
[image: Slide 1]