# How do I make the slideshow caption responsive and disappear when page is minimized?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, slideshow

I am working on a website which I coded from scratch.

I am using the following to help me insert captions on to my carousel slides which is working quite well:
[Adding text over an image in Bootstrap carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29734492/adding-text-over-an-image-in-bootstrap-carousel)

Everything is responsive. The only issue is that when I minimize the page to mobile size the captions appear on top of the slides. Is there any way to make them disappear once the page reaches a certain size?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [css media query](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).
Just add a style rule to your css files, for example something like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .caption {
        display: hidden;
    }
}
```

For max-width you can of course use any pixel value you like. All styles inside of the media query are only applied if the condition is met, so in this case, if the screen width is 500px or less.